# Flow typing issue on conditional object property

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I'm having this flow issue `string [1] is not an object` with the following code:

```js
type User = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  gender?: string,
}

const user: User = {
  name: 'xxx',
  age: 23,
  ...(props.gender && { gender: props.gender })   // <----- the culprit is this line
}
```

Do you know why?
Seems like conditionally setting a key is not correctly supported with the object rest spread operator.

I solved it doing:

```js
const user: User = {
  name: 'xxx',
  age: 23,
}
if (props.gender) {
  user.gender = props.gender
}
```

but I don't want to loose a language feature based on the flow typing.

Comment: Please include a complete example. Your code works fine here: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMAabKfW0vAV0ICMlGdXcAEyQB+MhWp1GAXwDcmTADd8yMIgD2YOKgxQBwxGQBEAd3XqjUOQoDG63BSjsEh2C51YcBYmQDkAD0DfPmZWMgAmAGYQgDo4gAo1TTgY-SQoADIM3TTXJK1UiCF06QBKHCgAekqoAB4AWkbGqGAAC2gbdgAbNSpgKCptNsGoLpoITDkgA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow is catching a legitimate type error bug in your code here. If `gender` were an empty string, your code equates to

```
const user: User = {
  name: 'xxx',
  age: 23,
  ...""
};
```

which, while not a runtime error, is definitely a weird type error. You should only ever use object spread syntax on an object.

The best fix here would either be to assign the property after, as you've done, or to do

```
...(props.gender ? { gender: props.gender } : null)
```

which clearly says "if gender is falsy, don't spread any properties". You could also use `{}` instead of `null`, but that just creates an extra object for no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. And good point for the `null` vs `{}` ;)
However, spread syntax should work similar to `Object.assign` and the later handle any primitives as `{}` so it should not trigger a flow type error.
But I agree, for the sake of clarity, adding the ternary is a more readable approach. Thanks!

Comment: Your comment regarding `gender` being an empty string doesn't seem correct to me. If `gender` were an empty string `''` it would coerce to `false` and therefore not conditionally spread.

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani Object spread uses object coercion as specified here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-toobject so there is no coercion to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through this [Github issue on object rest spread operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/issues/45) I found a better way to solve it. And this is by defaulting to an empty object.

So I changed this line:

```js
...(props.gender && { gender: props.gender })
```

with

```js
...((props.gender && { gender: props.gender }) || {})
```

and now the flow error is resolved.

Comment: If it will be ternary, make it a ternary operator instead. It's more simple to reason about a ternary: 
`...((props.gender ? { gender: props.gender }) : {})`